# Str_extract_all where replacement is keeping value between two character strings

Tags: r, replace, stringr

First time posting to SO so apologies in advance, I am also quite new to R so this may not be possible.

I am trying to format a string, (extracted from a JSON) where there is a value between 2 curly braces like so

```
{@link value1}
```

I am trying to replace the `{@link value1}` with `[[value1]]` so that it will work as a link in my markdown file.

I cannot just replace the opening and then the closing as there is also  `{@b value2}` which would be formatted to `**value2**`

I have cobbled together a str_replace that functions if there is only 1 link replacement needed in a string but I am running into an issue when there is two. Like so:

```
str <- c("This is the first {@link value1} and this is the second {@link value2}")
```

The actual potential strings are much more varied than this

My plan was to build a function to take input as to the type of pattern needed either `bold or link` and then paste the strings with the extracted value in the middle to form the replacement

However that has either left me with

```
This is the first [[ value1 ]][[ value2 ]] and this is the second [[ value1 ]][[ value2 ]]
or
This is the first [[ value1 ]] and this is the second [[ value1 ]]
```

Is there a more glamorous way of achieving this without searching from where the last } was replaced?

I was looking at the example of the [documentation of stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) for str_replace and it uses an example of a function at the bottom but I can't de-code it to try using for my example

What I'm using to extract the value incl the curly braces

```
str_extract_all(str,"(\\{@link ).+?(\\})")
[[1]]
[1] "{@link value1}" "{@link value2}"
```

What I'm using to extract the value excl the curly braces and tag

```
str_extract_all(str,"(?<=\\{@link ).+?(?=\\})")
[[1]]
[1] "value1" "value2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str_replace_all()` to perform multiple replacements by passing a named vector (`c(pattern1 = replacement1)`) to it. References of the form `\\1`, `\\2`, etc. will be replaced with the contents of the respective matched group created by `()`.

```r
str <- c("This is the first {@link value1} and this is the second {@b value2}")

str_replace_all(str, c("\\{@link\\s+(.+?)\\}" = "[[\\1]]",
                       "\\{@b\\s+(.+?)\\}"    = "**\\1**"))

# [1] "This is the first [[value1]] and this is the second **value2**"
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly! 
So if im understanding this the \\s in the patten represents the string and then the \\1 refrences it in the replacement section?
Looks like I need to brush up on references as I have a feeling this may be benefical in other parts I am working on!

Comment: @ThomasGorman `\\s` means all the whitespace characters including `" "`, `\t`, `\r`, `\n`, `\v`, `\f`.